# I have a tree kind of structure on click of each node I get the child node, i.e tree is not defined and depends on server response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My dataStructure looks like this-

```
{
  "id": "4e066148-383e-4a1c-871e-3b0c75dd8038",
  "nodeName": "East Elevation Area B Level 2",
  "parentId": "5946c931-9afc-43ab-aea3-240cfe802a1d",
  "childNodes": [],
  "__typename": "projectLocationTree"
},
```

When I click on each node I get the children. Now I'm not getting how can I add the children to the tree.

```
const fetchProjectLocationTreeData = async (currentId = null) => {
  try {
    dispatch(setIsLoading(true));
    let responseData;
    if (currentId === null) {
      responseData = await client.query({
        query: LOAD_INITIAL_LOCATION_DATA,
        variables: {
          projectId: Number(pathMatch.params.projectId),
        },
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        context: { role: myProjectRole.viewMyProjects },
      });
    } else {
      responseData = await client.query({
        query: LOAD_LOCATION_DATA,
        variables: {
          projectId: Number(pathMatch.params.projectId),
          currentId: currentId,
        },
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        context: { role: myProjectRole.viewMyProjects },
      });
    }
    setParentNodeId(parentId);
    let list: any = [];
    if (responseData.data.projectLocationTree.length > 0) {
      list = transformLocationData(responseData.data.projectLocationTree);
      if (list[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
        // list[0].isOpen = true;
        // list[0].isLoaded = true;
      }
    }
    console.log("before update location Item", locationItem);
    const updatedLocationItem = [...locationItem];
    const index = updatedLocationItem.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id == parentNodeId
    );
    console.log("index", index);
    const parent = locationItem.find((node) => node.id == parentId);
    console.log("currentParent", parent);
    if (parent) {
      parent.childNodes = list;

      // Set the updated array as the new locationItem state
      setLocationItem(updatedNodes);
    } else {
      setLocationItem(list);
    }

    dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
    dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
  }
};
const transformLocationData = (
  argList: Array<LocationNode>
): Array<LocationNode> => {
  const returnValue: Array<LocationNode> = [];
  argList.forEach((item: LocationNode) => {
    const childNodes = computeChildNodes(item.childNodes);
    const newItem: LocationNode = new LocationNode(
      item.nodeName,
      item.parentId,
      item.id,
      childNodes
    );
    returnValue.push(newItem);
  });
  return returnValue;
};

const computeChildNodes = (
  argList: Array<LocationNode>
): Array<LocationNode> => {
  const returnValue: Array<LocationNode> = [];
  if (argList) {
    argList.forEach((item: LocationNode) => {
      const childNodes = computeChildNodes(item.childNodes);
      const newItem: LocationNode = new LocationNode(
        item.nodeName,
        item.parentId,
        item.id,
        childNodes
      );
      returnValue.push(newItem);
    });
  }
  return returnValue;
};
```

I'm setting all the data in a single state i.e locationItem.

I'm doing it in React. Can you please suggest a approach. I'm doing two API call first time when the parent id is null and second time when there is id. the id which I'm passing is current node id. and the API gives me the childnodes. Now how can I show it on UI